# R: Best practice to add information to data in wide format and transform it to long format

Tags: r, pivot, data-wrangling

I am trying to transform some time course data from wide format into long format, which also requires adding some more information to the original data.
The original data follows this structure:

```r
ID      Exp_01 Exp_02 Exp_03 Exp_04 Exp_05 ...
"AA"    0.01   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.01
"BB"    0.01   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.01
"CC"    0.01   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.01
"DD"    0.01   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.01
"EE"    0.01   0.02   0.03   0.05   0.01
...
```

The "Exp_XY" tags are a time series with 7 time points that are each measured three times under three different experimental conditions, so they continue until "Exp_63".

To illustrate, `Exp_01, Exp_02, Exp_03` belong to time point `t1` for condition `cond1`. `Exp_04, Exp_05, Exp_06` belong to time point `t2` for condition `cond1`, and so on.

I managed to transform the data into long format with `pivot_longer` with this command:

```
raw %>% pivot_longer(!ID, names_to="experimentID", values_to="count")
```

I want to add the information of the time points as well as the experimental condition to the original data, transform it into long format, and use it for downstream analysis. However, I am stuck at this point, and hope that somebody could help to solve the following questions:

1. What is the best practice to add information about the time points and experimental conditions to the original data. Is it better to add it before or after the transformation into long format?
2. Depending on the answer for 1), how is the information actually added?

The desired output would look something like this:

```
ID   experimentID time condition count
"AA" "Exp_01"     "t1" "cond1"   0.01
"AA" "Exp_02"     "t1" "cond1"   0.02
"AA" "Exp_03"     "t1" "cond1"   0.03

"AA" "Exp_04"     "t2" "cond1"   0.05
"AA" "Exp_05"     "t2" "cond1"   0.01
"AA" "Exp_06"     "t2" "cond1"   0.03
...
"AA" "Exp_61"     "t7" "cond3"   0.05
"AA" "Exp_62"     "t7" "cond3"   0.05
"AA" "Exp_63"     "t7" "cond3"   0.05
"BB" "Exp_01"     "t1" "cond1"   0.01
"BB" "Exp_02"     "t1" "cond1"   0.02
...
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I'd suggest pivoting long, then using `separate(experimentID, c("stub", "num"), convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE)` to extract the number from the column. Then the last step would be to convert your column label number into time / condition, perhaps using some combination of modulo `%%`, integer division `%/%`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @Jon! For now, I think @Ronak's solution solves this problem very elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `rep` and `paste0` to create `time` and `condition` columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- raw %>% 
  pivot_longer(!ID, names_to="experimentID", values_to="count") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(time = rep(paste0('time', 1:7), each = 3, 3), 
         condition = rep(paste0('cond', 1:3), each = 21))

result
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ronak! I tried your solution and ran into a dimensional problem with both `time` and `condition`.


`
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `time`.
 `time = rep(paste0("time", 1:7), each = 3, 3)`.
 `time` must be size 174 or 1, not 63.
`

174 refers to the total number of IDs. I am not sure how to solve this, though.

Comment: Is every `ID` unique in your original dataset? I mean does `'AA'`, `'BB'`, `'CC'` occur only once in `raw` ? Also if you have `plyr` loaded in your environment use `dplyr::mutate` instead of `mutate`.

Comment: Yes, every `ID` is unique, so each of them only occurs once in `raw`. 
I guess the error is related to the question when to add the extra information about time and conditions? The `raw` data has 174 rows due to 174 unique `ID`s, and 63 columns for the sequential time points, plus one column which contains the `ID`s.

Comment: `tmp <- raw %>% pivot_longer(!ID, names_to="experimentID", values_to="count")` What is `nrow(tmp)` ? It should be `174 X 63` right? For every `ID` you'll have 63 rows.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct! `nrow(tmp)` retrieves 10962.

Comment: Hmm..then the solution should work. Did you try using `dplyr::mutate` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using `dplyr::mutate`. I tried commenting out `time` and `condition` separately (which both gave the dimensional error), as well as commenting out `dplyr::mutate` completely. The latter basically gives the same output as in the `tmp` example. Somehow, `mutate` expects the dimensions of the IDs, and not of the `experiment_ID`s.

Comment: I made a mistake in my code, I am really sorry, your code works perfectly fine!